# Django model is refering itself

Tags: python, django, django-users

I am using the django user model and want to create a logic that which user has been registered by which user like admin as a user can only register another employee or admin as a user.
Means an entry in the user model can be created by another user(user in the same user model) under some business logic. 
I want to reference/know which user belongs to which user.and don't wanna create a new model to do this until no way left.
please help me with this.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [self reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) the same model by using

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: help me with one more thing. I wanna all the users either created by the current logged in user and the current user. how to write Django query in views.py